# How to prevent nil values in Ecto Changeset?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an `update_changeset` in which I want to prevent `nil` values from being written.

I tried adding a `validate_change`

```
 def update_changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:full_name])
    |> validate_change(:full_name, fn :full_name, full_name ->
      if full_name == nil do
        [full_name: "cannot be blank"]
      else
        []
      end
    end)
  end
```

But since it only gets called when a non-nil value is present, it still lets me write full_name: nil into the database.

How can I make this work?

Updated: here is how I implemented from help from fellows:

```
defp prevent_empty(changeset, fields) do
    Enum.reduce(fields, changeset, fn field, changeset ->
      value = get_field(changeset, field)

      if value in ["", nil] do
        add_error(changeset, field, "cannot be empty or blank")
      else
        changeset
      end
    end)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to handle it manually, with a help of [`Ecto.Changeset.add_error/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#add_error/4).

```elixir
def update_changeset(user, %{full_name: fn} = attrs) do
  user
  |> cast(attrs, [:full_name])
  |> prevent_empty_full_name()
end

defp prevent_empty_full_name(%{changes: %{full_name: full_name}} = changeset)
    when full_name in ["", nil],
  do: add_error(changeset, :full_name, "empty")

defp prevent_empty_full_name(changeset),
  do: changeset
```

Comment: Thanks! I will updated my original question with my final solution which I will use, which will take in multiple fields as a list :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [validate_required/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3).

> If the value of a field is nil or a string made only of whitespace,
> the changeset is marked as invalid, the field is removed from the
> changeset's changes, and an error is added.

```
 def update_changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:full_name])
    |> validate_required([:full_name])
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue with that is that I want to be able to send the update payload without having :full_name. With `validate_required` it makes that field required. I only want to check that it cannot be set to `nil`.

Comment: So you want to allow an empty `""` but not `nil`?

Comment: Yeah, I want both to be not allowed. Basically it cannot be empty/blank for updates.

Comment: Gotcha -- take a look at Aleksei's answer.  Sometimes you have to roll your own manipulations of the `%Changeset{}`